# TypeError when I try to run mt Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, typeerror

I'm trying to get the sample program from REST API Development With Node.js working. When I try to run it I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at translateTypeToJs (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/lib/db.js:93:8)
    at translateComplexType (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/lib/db.js:58:21)
    at _.each (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/lib/db.js:83:13)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:191:9)
    at Object.getModelFromSchema (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/lib/db.js:76:5)
    at module.exports (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/models/book.js:7:21)
    at module.exports (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/models/index.js:3:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Books/REST API Development With Node.js/lib/db.js:21:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I've been through the code and even checked the [GitHub project](https://github.com/marley-nodejs/Pro-Rest-API-Development-with-Node.js/blob/master/lib/db.js) but can't see what I've done wrong. Frm the log above it seems to be calling `translateTypeToJs` from the default case. I've checked this with what is in the book and it's the exact same. How do I fix this?

This is my code for lib/db.js:

```
const config = require("config"),
  _ = require("underscore"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),

  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let obj = {
  cachesModels: {},
  getModelFromSchema: getModelFromSchema,
  model: function(mname) {
    return this.models[mname]
  },
  connect: function(cb) {
    mongoose.connect(config.database.host + "/" + config.database.dbname);
    this.connection = mongoose.connection;
    this.connection.on('error', cb);
    this.connection.on('open', cb);
  }
}

obj.models = require("../models/")(obj);

module.exports = obj;

function translateComplexType(v, strType) {
  let tmp = null;
  let type = strType || v['type'];
  switch(type) {
    case 'array':
      tmp = [];
      if(v['items']['$ref'] != null) {
        tmp.push({
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: v['items']['$ref']
        });
      } else {
        let originalType = v['items']['type'];
        v['items']['type'] = translateTypeToJs(v['items']['type']);
        tmp.push(translateComplexType(v['items'], originalType));
      }
    break;
    case 'object':
      tmp = {};
      let props = v['properties'];
      _.each(props, (data, k) => {
        if(data['$ref'] != null) {
          tmp[k] = {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: data['$ref']
          }
        } else {
          tmp[k] = translateTypeToJs(data['type']);
        }
      });
    break;
    default:
      tmp = v;
      tmp['type'] = translateTypeToJs(type);
    break;
  }
  return tmp;
}


/**
 * Turns the JSON Schema into a Mongoose schema
 */
function getModelFromSchema(schema){
  let data = {
    name: schema.id,
    schema: {}
  }

  let newSchema = {};
  let tmp = null;
  _.each(schema.properties, (v, propName) => {
    if(v['$ref'] != null) {
      tmp = {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: v['$ref']
      }
    } else {
      tmp = translateComplexType(v) //{}
    }
    newSchema[propName] = tmp;
  });
  data.schema = new Schema(newSchema);
  return data;
}


function translateTypeToJs(t) {
  if(t.indexOf('int') === 0) {
    t = "number";
  }
  return eval(t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1));
}
```

Comment: console.log(v['items']['type'])  before calling translateTypeToJs and check what it is logging

Comment: In Line 93:   if(t.indexOf('int') === 0) I guess you need to check first if t is not empty or the correct type like `if(t && t.indexOf('int') === 0)`

Comment: @McRist your tip made me realise that there was an issue with my schema. Once I sorted that I got past this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the issue was due to an incorrect schema structure. Once fixed I no longer hit this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if the meaning of the comment on line `translateComplexType(v) //{}` is that `v` can be an empty object on that line, then:

- the line `let type = strType || v['type']` can make `type === undefined`
- and `translateTypeToJs(undefined)` call will be made on `tmp['type'] = translateTypeToJs(type)` (thus throwing the TypeError)

I would suggest following fix:

```
let type = strType || v['type'] || 'undefined'
```